# how to Convert special characters to parsable format in an XML file

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm new to C# and XML and all this things. Well, I'm trying to parse an XML file contains special characters like `&`, `<` etc and even the file contains more than 10,000 lines.

I'm using

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlFile);
```

but whenever it encounters character like `&` throws exception. 
It can change from `&` to `&#38;`, `<` to `&#60;`
And because of it contains many lines its almost impossible to convert them all manually.

So, please suggest me the best way to solve the problem. Or if possible then some sample code.

input: xml string (contains special char).

Comment: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/09/how-to-replace-escape-xml-special-characters-java-string.html

Comment: Your document is not correct and that's why parsing library cannot load it. Don't expect incorrect XML to be parsed correctly. Fix it before parsing.

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316063   C#

Comment: Visit [This Link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308060/en-us) I think it may help to solve your problem. Also there are different ways to escape special character in XML [Different ways to escape XML](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2008/10/21/Different-ways-how-to-escape-an-XML-string-in-C.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

This error occur when your document is incorrect.

Anyway , you can try this

First load your file in a string variable named as response

```
TextReader stringRead = new StringReader(response);
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(stringRead);
```